# SendMessage winapi Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

I think it's easy, i found some winapi example but i don't understand how they work. I want send a message on a "process", like 'notepad.exe' how can i? Ex: i press number '1' script send & write only on notepad.exe '1, 2, 3, 4, hello' or something like that, i really don't understand how... Here an example of what i try to do

```
if '1' is pressed:
    sendmessage = 'notepad.exe', '2, 3, 4, hello'
```

Can someone explain me how winapi work too?
Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: actually it's not easy at all.  instead of trying to build this from scratch, take a look at AutoHotkey.  AHK has its own programming language; if you want to really want to program this logic in python, do a search and you'll find python libraries that wrap AHK or provide a subset of its capabilities.

Comment: UIAutomation is the platform automation library

Comment: Import `pyHook` to hook keyboard press. Use `win32gui.Findwindow` to get the handle of notepad windows, then try to get it's childwindow handle of edit control, `win32gui.SendMessage(edithandle, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, ...)` sends the key to notepad. Can this meet your need?

Comment: @Jeffrey you can't reliably fake input this way, as has been discussed many times here and elsewhere